Cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to determine the version
The version of my java is 21.
However the error says it's looking for v17.
I tried to find and fix the problem. But there aren't any solution to this available. I am trying to avoid reinstalling Android Studio.
This is mac m1. Please guide me here.
[1

I was able to resolve this with the help of chatgpt...
Flutter was pointing to the wrong jdk all this while...
Run the cmd: flutter config --list
I got this...

All Settings:
enable-web: true
...
...
jdk-dir: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/
android-studio-dir: /Applications/Android Studio.app

jdk-dir was set to old version of java...
I was able to update this with the following cmd
flutter config --jdk-dir /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home 
Now when I run flutter doctor, I'm getting this


Solved using this way.

I think the issue lies with the version of java used by default. Android studio V34 (at least the gradle version, which some plugins may use) uses Java 17. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/build/jdks#compileSdk and see if this might help.
PS - I don't think you need to reinstall Android Studio, just install the version of Java it wants

thanks for trying to help. But the issue was something else. I'm going to add the solution now.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Here's how i fixed it.
First, run the cmd: flutter config --list
You should see a jdk path which is the one not working.
Now, open Finder > Go to Folder > type /Library/Java/press Enter.
Now, manually open the folder JavaVirtualMachines.
Inside this folder you should see the currently installed jdk version you have on your machine.
In my case it was jdk-22.jdk, whatever version you have take note of it.
Now, in your terminal run the following cmd, but insert your version, in my case it was version 22:
flutter config /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-22.jdk/Contents/Home

Run again flutter doctor.
You should have solved.

Update the JDK Path
You can directly update the JDK path using the flutter config command:
flutter config --jdk-dir /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home

then run
flutter doctor

this work for me
